# Don't save certain command in history

Tags: vim

I have a shortcut in `.vimrc`:

```
map <silent> ,w :wall <CR>
```

I don't want to see this command (:wall) when I am browsing history in vim. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As you're running the command from a mapping, you shouldn't be seeing the command in your history at all, but for removing items from history, see `:help histdel()`.